# EEXIST without IPC_EXCL on shmget

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I have a strange problem with shared memory.

Method `shmget` returns -1 and `errno` is set to `EEXIST`. According to man, it is only possible when both flag `IPC_EXCL` and `IPC_CREAT` are provided.

My code:

```
int main()
{
        int shmid = shmget(0xABCD, MAX_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0x660);
        int shmid2 = shmget(0xABCD, MAX_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0x660 );
        if(shmid == -1)
        {
                if(errno == EEXIST)
                        perror("Error");
                return -1;
        }
        if(shmid2 == -1)
        {
                if(errno == EEXIST)
                        perror("Error2");
                return -1;
        }
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

It compiles with -Wall without warnings, I check with ipcs if the segment is already present (and remove it if needed). The output is `Error2: File exists`.
It works when I change the second shmget to:

```
int shmid2 = shmget(0xABCD, MAX_SIZE, 0 );
```

Quote from `man shmget`:

```
EEXIST     IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL was specified and the segment exists.
```

And one more question: is it true, that mode_flags (i.e. 0x660) are not used when trying to execute shmget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permission modes need to be specified in *octal*, not hexadecimal.  `0x660` (hex) = `03140` (octal).  And the `IPC_EXCL` flag has the octal value `02000` in the Linux ABI -- so by using `0x660` instead of `0660` you are accidentally setting `IPC_EXCL`, which is why you get the error.

If I change both instances of `0x660` to `0660` in your program and fix the other things that make it not compile (notably, you left out all the headers and the definition of `MAX_SIZE`) it works as expected.

Comment: That is the most embarrassing moment ever. Like... Ever... Don't even know what to say to cover my shame, I use octal in system calls almost every day... Thanks for help :)

Comment: @xavier - On the long list of bonehead mistakes we make in life this one won't even be close to the top.  Better to avoid all of this and just use the symbolic constants e.g. S_IRUSR, S_IRGRP and so forth.  It's more portable and less headaches.

Comment: @Duck I dunno about that, I can read and comprehend `0660` a *lot* faster than `S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP`.

Comment: @Zack it's true, because it's a standard syntax, but constants seem to be less error prone.